# Верны ли знаки препинания в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Чтобы восстановить крымскую промышленность, понадобится немало времени.

Comment: Извините, но Ваш выбор правильного ответа странен! Вы же ведь не спрашивали (в шапке): _СКОЛЬКО знаков препинания в предложении?_ Собственно предложение всегда заканчивается каким-либо знаком препинания (оно не остается "беспрепинательно висеть" в воздухе).

Answer (score 2):

Здесь только один знак препинания ― запятая  в сложноподчиненном предложении с придаточным цели. А какие еще могут быть варианты, что вызывает сомнение?

Comment: А Вы скажите, сколько здесь знаков препинания?